# jQuery click() and on() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add "active" class to menu when user clicks on the button but for some reason it's not working correctly. They have to click really fast and two times. I've tried both click and on click function but still not working.

```js
       $('#menu li').click(function() {
         $('#menu li.active').removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass('active');
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="menu">
    <li class="nav active"><a href="?load=index">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="?load=about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="?load=services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="?load=gallery">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="?load=contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly.

Comment: You need to parse the url or add the class server side. Clicking on link loads new page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must handle active li after page loaded.Add this at the end of your code:

```
        var curruntLocation = window.location.href;

        $('#menu li a').each(function ()
        {
            var thisHref = $(this).attr('href');
            if (curruntLocation.indexOf(thisHref) > 0)
            {
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');                    
            }
        });
```

Comment: You welcome. If you want others use your post, It is better to set a more related Title. For example: How to find active menu by url.

Answer (score 0):

The links included in the menu items are reloading the page while clicking and when the page is reloaded, the initial setting comes first. You can use `preventDefault()` if you'd like to run the function but then, your links won't work.

I suggest you use anchors instead of query string.

Comment: Aw, that's it... Makes sense. Well, I have index.php template that loads all content from other templates inside a div element and was trying to figure out how to make the active class stay.

Comment: You can load each content in a separate div and set display: none for all of them except the first-child (by giving class .active to it). Then, while clicking a menu item, add an active class to the relevant div as well and make the active div visible with CSS.

Comment: That sounds like a possible solution. Will try it out! Thank you!

Comment: Be right back in few minutes. I'm creating a fiddle for you.

Comment: No need. Someone figured out how to make it work with jQuery. Thank you anyway!